# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, smtp, system.net.mail

I'm in the process of upgrading my web pages from asp classic to asp.net.  My previous code used CDO to send emails.

```
sch = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/" 
                Set cdoConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration") 

                    With cdoConfig.Fields 
                        .Item(sch & "sendusing") = 2 
                        .Item(sch & "smtpserver") = "mail.mydomain.com" 
                        .update 
                    End With 

                Set cdoMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 

                    strTo = "toaddr@mydomain.com"

                strFrom = "fromaddr@mydomain.com"

                strSubject = "email subject"
                strBody = strBody & "This is the email body"


                With cdoMessage 
                        Set .Configuration = cdoConfig 
                        .From = strFrom
                        .To =  strTo
                        .Subject = strSubject
                        .HTMLBody = strBody
                        .Send 
                End With

                Set cdoConfig = Nothing
                Set cdoMessage = Nothing
```

This code works fine but I'd like to send emails from my asp.net pages.  When I send from the .net pages, I get the error message: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it xx.xx.xxx.xxx:2 "

My web.config settings:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp from="myemail@mydomain.com">
            <network host="mail.mydomain.com" port="2"/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

And the section of code that is giving me the error:

```
        Dim mailmsg As New MailMessage("myemail@mydomain.com", txtSubmitterEmail.Text)

        mailmsg.Subject = "subject here"
        mailmsg.Body = "mail body here"
        mailmsg.IsBodyHtml = True

        Dim smtp As New SmtpClient

        smtp.Send(mailmsg)
```

I'm rather new to .Net but I've searched for hours and can not come up with a reason why the old code works but the new doesn't.  Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SMTP server you want to reach is probably on port 25.

```
<network host="mail.mydomain.com" port="25"/>
```

This is different from the `sendusing` directive.

Comment: In case the OP missed it: when the error message reports "xx.xx.xxx.xxx:2", the last number is the port number. SMTP is conventionally on port 25.

Comment: Thanks! That worked.  I didn't try port 25 because the code using CDO was working using port 2.